# Is there any way to map a ISO Currency Code back to a culture string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, telerik

We maintain a master data table in SQL that contains the currency code, description, and symbol of all currencies our company  does business in. In total there are 32. Example;

USD, US Dollar, $

These codes are used to look up exchange rate information which is automatically inserted into another SQL table. All of our .NET applications support these currencies. A user sets their preferred currency in their profile.

We just recently starting using Telerik controls, and the RadNumericTextBox control takes a culture string as a property (i.e en-US) which handles all culture specific settings (symbol, separator, grouping, etc) which makes monetary input quite nice for a user, but this creates an issue.

Now to the actual issue. I bind a drop down list with a list of objects, and in order to have all required information for the telerik controls and exchange rate information the underlying values need to be in this format. Example;

: --> en-US:USD

Logic that builds the currency objects

```
 public static List<Currency> BuildCurrencyObjects()
    {
        List<Currency> currencies = new List<Currency>();
        List<Currency> dbCurrencies = CurrencyMgmt.GetCurrencies();

        foreach (Currency currency in dbCurrencies)
        {
            var region = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                                    .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID))
                                    .Where(ri => ri != null && ri.ISOCurrencySymbol == currency.CurrenyCode)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();

            if (region != null)
            {
                var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
                                         .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith((region as RegionInfo).Name))
                                         .FirstOrDefault();
                if (culture != null)
                {
                    Currency c = new Currency()
                    {
                        CultureCode = culture.Name + ":" + region.ISOCurrencySymbol,
                        Symbol = culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol,
                        Description = region.CurrencyEnglishName,
                        CurrencyRegion = region.EnglishName,
                        CurrenyCode = region.Name
                    };

                    currencies.Add(c);
                }
            }
        }

        return currencies;
    }
```

I wrote this function pretty quickly and it appeared to work correctly. It creates 31 currency objects and displayed what appeared to be correct text in the drop down. I only realized there was an issue when it was moved to our test environment where the United States display text went from; and the value;

United States, US Dollar, $ --> Carribean, US Dollar, $
en-US:USD --> en-029:USD

I understand now that the above logic wont work since there are multiple cultures that map back to a currency code and Linq is returning the first element in the sequence. Is there any proficient way to map a currency code back to a culture string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Is not possible. Look what happen with the EURO. You could see a more examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)

Your solution should include a way to store the actual culture along with the currency.

Comment: I debated storing the culture code in the database, but for the time being since it was only the USD ISO code that was giving me issues; I added a bit of Linq that returns the Region object with the USA GeoID. Not the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done for the time being. I will revisit this when it moves to production on a global scale.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding there are many cultures that use a single currency code. This is because not all countries have their own currency. This means that there is no way to map a currency to map currency to a specific culture without hard coding the values or adding it to your database. Your best bet would be to probably add another column to the database that defines which culture that currency belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to set the language (e.g. en) hard-coded or set the CurrencyNegativePattern, CurrencyPositivePattern and the CurrencyDecimalSeperator implicitly (as suggested in [How to display the euro symbol at the front of the number when using CultureInfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47612295/how-to-display-the-euro-symbol-at-the-front-of-the-number-when-using-cultureinfo)).