# How to display the euro symbol at the front of the number when using CultureInfo?

Tags: c#, currency, cultureinfo

So I wanted to try display currency in C# and found CultureInfo, only thing is, there is no way to display the euro symbol at the front of the number, not from what I have seen and read.

Basically this:

```
float f = 100.50;
MoneyAmount.Text = f.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

will display: £100.50

this:

```
float f = 100.50;
MoneyAmount.Text = f.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

will display: $100.50

but this:

```
float f = 100.50;
MoneyAmount.Text = f.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

will display: 100.50 €

Is there any way for `fr-FR` to display the currency like this: €100.50?

Comment: Are you sure this is the right question to ask? If the France culture decides to show the currency symbol after the value, why should you say otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern` and `NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern` of the `CultureInfo` instance:

```
float f = 100.50f;
var culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 0;
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 2;
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator;
Console.WriteLine(f.ToString("C", culture));
```

Prints

```
    €100.50
```

Answer (score 3):

You can customize cultureinfo;

```
var frenchCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
frenchCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 0;
frenchCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 2;
frenchCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
double value = 100.50;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", frenchCulture)); // Output : €100.50
value = -100.50; //For negative currency
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", frenchCulture)); // Output : €-100.50
```

Comment: `frenchCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 0;
frenchCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";` will make the output exactly match what was asked for, `€100.50`

Answer (score 2):

Whoever commented with "put `en-FR` instead of `fr-FR`" so it would look like this:

```
MoneyAmount.Text = f.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-FR"));
```

Thank you Adrian, that did the trick. I didn't think `en-FR` existed because the only thing I found was `fr-FR`.

Comment: `en-IE` is a more common locale (as in it's a country the language is more commonly used in) that would have the same effect, but if what you really wanted was "French, as spoken in France, but with the Euro in front", then Rainman's answer is closer to that. (I'd also be cautious of money amounts in `float` values rather than `decimal`).

Comment: It was me who suggested it at first, but I have updated my answer with a better approach (that does not require changing the locale string)

Comment: Well thanks Adrian :)
Also its better for me just to change the locale string because what I have right now is a string array consisting of `en-GB, en-FR, en-US` and then binaryReader which reads the `what currency is being used` ID, so if its 0 then everything will have `£`, if 1 then `€` and if `2` then `$` and it would get the corresponding CultureInfo from the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CurrencyPositivePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern.aspx)
property on NumberFormatInfo class in your CultureInfo. When value 2 is used, it will change the position of currency symbol before number.